# Oracle SQL query using partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query :

```
select a.name, count(distinct numClient)
from a
group by a.name;
```

I would like to add another column that will count for each line the sum of the preceding lines :

```
JONES     3      0
SMITH     5      3
JOHN      10     8
.....
KEN       12     365
```

Can you help ?. I guess I have to use partition but do not understand it well.

Comment: do you have a column to specify the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a column to specify the order in which to calculate the cumulative sum, you can use

```
select name,cntClient,sum(cntClient) over(order by orderCol rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as cumCntClient
from (select a.name, count(distinct numClient) as cntClient
      from a
      group by a.name
     ) t
```

Comment: what is orderCol here ?

Comment: the order in which to calculate the cumulative sum..it can be `cntClient` per the example shown

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a subquery at all:

```
select a.name, count(distinct numClient),
       (sum(count(distinct numClient)) over (order by count(distinct numClient)) -
        count(distinct numClient)
       ) as running_sum
from a
group by a.name;
```